# How to fix "Column 'ColumnName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Tags: sql, group-by

Needing to fix the mentioned code error for my SQL query

Error: "Column 'ColumnName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I am under the impression that an aggregate function needs to be implemented, however I do not understand how.

My query:

```
SELECT 
TransactionID,
InvoiceSum.TransNum,
PosTransaction.OrderID,
PosTransaction.PatientID, 
Patient.ID,
Patient.MedicalRecordNum,
PosTransaction.OfficeNum AS Pos_OfficeNum,
Patient.ExamOffice,
TransactionDate,
Patient.FirstName,
Patient.LastName,
Patient.BirthDate,
Patient.Sex,
Item.ItemNum,
Item.ItemName
FROM PosTransaction Inner Join Patient ON PosTransaction.PatientID = 
Patient.ID

Inner Join InvoiceSum ON PosTransaction.TransactionID = 
InvoiceSum.TransNum
Inner Join InvoiceDet ON InvoiceSum.InvoiceID = InvoiceDet.InvoiceID
Inner Join Item ON InvoiceDet.ItemID = Item.ID

GROUP BY Patient.ID

ORDER BY TransactionDate
```

I am expecting to see duplicate customer names to be removed from the output once properly I understand how to use GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only group by patient.ID, what will happen to other columns? 
(The server does not know what it should do, so it raises an error)

The server does not know what you want to do with the other columns.
(So You need the aggregate function(s) to tell the SQL server)

Simple example:

```
ID|salary
01|1000
01|2000
01|3000
```

If I only group by id here:

```
select id, salary
from sample
group by id
```

How do you want to calculate salary? Sum, max, min?
So you need the aggregate function:

```
select id, sum(salary)
from sample
group by id
```

Comment below if you have any questions.